# Rails/Heroku : db:push runs correctly but does not create the DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've been having problems yesterday with Heroku shared Postgres DB. It looks like my db is not correctly 'pushed' to my heroku DB.

### Configuration

Using 'pg' gem for both development and production environments.
Using Heroku's 'shared-database' add-on.
Running Rails 3.1.1.

### What I'm trying to do

Push my source code to Heroku and then synchronize my postgres DB with Heroku's one. No problem for the source itself, but I can't get my DB up and running.

### What I've tried so far

1: Source code push : `git push heroku master`. OK. This works.

2: Then I try to run : `heroku db:push`. Seems to be running normally, no error, the schema is sent to Heroku, the different tables are correctly detected and seem to be sent as well :

[image: heroku db:push]

3: Let's check it out, is everything allright ? `heroku info` :

[image: heroku info]

Doh ! The database is still empty (and therefore I get DB-related errors when accessing dynamic pages). Can't understand what's happening, I've spent time on this issue yesterday evening but only been mpessing with Heroku for a little while and never encountered this issue. Any clues ?

Comment: Can you add output of your db:push command ?

Comment: Done, added the db:push output.

Comment: Have you tried to execute "heroku restart". That what man should do after db:migrate and I'm not sure about db:push...

Comment: Yes I've tried the heroku restart. To be honest, I've even tried removing my app (it was used as a testing website) and creating a new one to check if I didn't mess something up. Didn't work though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not convinced that the Database size figure is a live figure. Here's a clean deployment of an app to Heroku and the output of `heroku info` at each stage. The first run is post application creation, the second after a push of the code, the third after a heroku db:push.

The database was uploaded before the third output and the application is running however the DB:size is not reporting the figure.

Is your application actually erroring because the database isn't present?

[image: heroku info output]

Comment: Well I used to have DB related errors but I don't have anymore. And I tried running a "heroku run console" to check whether ActiveRecord commands were working and it seems they are. Database size is indeed not working, and it looks like my problem is coming from somewhere else. Thanks for the pointer !

Comment: I'm checking with Heroku as to the frequency of the Database size refresh - it will be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the commit process.
You should run manually after each commit from your console :

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Enjoy
daniel